# not able to print exact value with double data type

Tags: java

Am trying to print the input given in variable double d, but not getting for all the scenarios:

Input:
235345345345.234534
123123232
0

Expected output:
2.3534534534523453E11
1.23123232E8
0.0

my code:
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Solution {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);


    double d1 = scan.nextDouble();        
    String d = String.valueOf(d1);        

    System.out.println("Double: " + d);

}
```

}

Comment: You probably need `BigDecimal` instead of `double`, with that many significant figures.

Comment: So what is the actual problem you are facing

Comment: how do i get output: 2.3534534534523453E11 for input:  235345345345.234534

Comment: by using `BigDecimal` instead of `double`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be in the unexpected decimal separator that depends on locale. For my default locale ("ru_RU") expected decimal separator is "**,**". In my case the code produces expected output for input "**235345345345,234534**".